# Is it possible to force the html canvas tag to display children?

Tags: css, html, canvas

Basically exactly as I asked. I'd like the following to work:

```
<canvas width="100" height="100" style="position: relative">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px"></div>
</canvas>
```

I realize that the contents of the canvas tag are usually only displayed as fallback, but I'd like to display the contents always.

Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score 3):

No, not in a way that works portably.

However, you can position the div on the coordinates of the canvas quite easily with a bit of javascript.

Comment: But that requires the div to be a sibling, I was hoping to make it a child regardless. Unless you're talking about something else?

Comment: Yeah, it would have to be a sibling.

Comment: Child elements are meant as a fall back for when the browser doesn't support the canvas tag. You'll need to use positioned siblings.